# SSO - SAML request

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml

Is SAML request sent everytime a user tries to load a service provider page ? If not, how does it handles the case when in some cases authentication is required as when session times out or someone tries to load a page when not loggedin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The analogy is would you require the user to login locally every time a user attempted to load a page? If the user doesn't have a local authentication session (eg authentication cookie), the SP performs SAML SSO to the IdP and uses information returned in the SAML assertion to automatically login the user and establish a local authentication session. If the authentication session times out, the SP can perform SAML SSO again.

Comment: Is the authentication session / cookie same for all the service providers, i mean do they share a common cookie ?

Comment: No. Each service provider has its own authentication cookie.